# How to upload video to server once and have it encode high quality, low quality, and mobile

Tags: html, video, drupal-7, h.264, encode

I would like to upload a very high quality (hd) video and have it automatically render in a lower quality (for slower connections) and mobile compatible quality.

I'm currently set up on Drupal using the Sublime Video HTML5 player which works well. What I don't want to have to do is encode every video 3 times and upload them separately.

I'm open to any kind of solution that would solve the problem of *upload once, encode many times*. If this doesn't "exist" can you please provide some insight on what it would take to make this happen on the server side?

An example on the web of this is when you upload a video to YouTube. It takes care of encoding it for every device, and I would like to emulate that.

Comment: you can use ffmpeg library for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of an actual implementation library that handles this but you're going to need to handle the encoding in a background process otherwise you'll tie up the web response (and future web responses) until all encoding has finished.

Keep that in mind as you're exploring solutions :)